# add href to Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, href

I have made a calendar using a repeater. It will list all of the days correctly etc. Eventually it will take bookings for each day. What id like to do now, is to make each of the day numbers to be a link, using aspx page. The part i'd link to make a link is this area "<%# Eval("DAY") %>". I want it to redirect to my bookings.aspx page. Thanks for any help.

C#:

```
public partial class Calendar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int month = 1;
    int year = 2014;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        month = int.Parse(CurrentDate.Value);
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo monthname = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        string strMonthName = monthname.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
        MonthLabel.Text = strMonthName;
        YearLabel.Text = year.ToString();
        List<DayOb> thismonthsdays = new List<DayOb>();
        string datefirst = month.ToString() + "/1/" + year.ToString();
        DateTime fst = DateTime.Parse(datefirst);
        int dow = (int)fst.DayOfWeek;
        for (int i = 0; i < dow; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                thismonthsdays.Add(new DayOb { CSS = "day sunday", Day = "X" });
            }
            else
            {
                thismonthsdays.Add(new DayOb { CSS = "day", Day = "X" });
            }

        }
        int endofmonth = fst.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Date.Day;
        for (int i = 1; i <= endofmonth; i++)
        {
            DayOfWeek thisdow = DateTime.Parse(month.ToString() + "/" + i.ToString() + "/" + year.ToString()).DayOfWeek;
            thismonthsdays.Add(new DayOb { CSS = "day " + thisdow.ToString().ToLower(), Day = i.ToString() });
        }
        cal.DataSource = thismonthsdays;
        cal.DataBind();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
    class DayOb
    {
        public string CSS { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="cal" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class='day sunday header'>

            Su
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            M
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            T
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            W
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            T
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            F
        </div>
        <div class='day header'>
            Sa
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class='<%# Eval("CSS") %>'>
            <%# Eval("DAY") %>

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `<a href='bookings.aspx'><%# Eval("DAY") %></a>`

Comment: wow thanks! very quick reply. works perfect. thank you sir =) is there a way to make the X days not have a link by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HyperLink` like

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDetails" 
 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DAY", "~/bookings.aspx?ID={0}") %>'
 runat="server">
    <%# Eval("DAY") %>
 </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: thank you sir, this works even better than the above answer. eventually i want to look through a database of bookings, and bring up the correct id for each day. this seems to be what i was after. thank you very much =)

Comment: thanks for that. brand new to the site. thanks again for your help. take care